# Google Apps Script - Usage of "indexOf" method

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

first: I really tried hard to get along, but I am more a supporter than a programmer.

I put some Text in Google Calc and wanted to check the amount of the occurances of "Mueller, Klaus" (It appears 5 times within the data range). The sheet contains 941 rows and 1 Column ("A").

Here is my code to find out:

```
function countKlaus() {
  
  // Aktives Spreadsheet auswählen

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  
  // Aktives Tabellenblatt auswählen
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");

  var start = 1;
  var end = sheet.getLastRow();

  var data = sheet.getRange(start,1,end,1).getValues();
  var curRow = start;
  var cntKlaus = 0;
  
  for( x in data )
  {
    var value = daten[x];
    //ui.alert(value);
    if(value.indexOf("Mueller, Klaus")> -1){
      cntKlaus = cntKlaus + 1;
    }
  }
 
  ui.alert(cntKlaus);
  
}
```

The result message is "0" but should be "5".

Comment: Index0f() can use a second parameter which is a starting index check you favorite JavaScript reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues:

You are very close to the solution, except for these two issues:

- `daten[x]` should be replaced by `data[x]`.
- `ui.alert(cntKlaus)` should be replaced by `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(cntKlaus)`.

### Solution (optimized by me) - Recommended:

```
function countKlaus() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
  const cntKlaus = sheet
                   .getRange('A1:A' + sheet.getLastRow())
                   .getValues()
                   .flat()
                   .filter(r=>r.includes("Mueller, Klaus"))
                   .length;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(cntKlaus);
}
```

You can leave out this term `+ sheet.getLastRow()` since we are filtering on a non-blank value. But I think it will be faster to have less data to use filter on in the first place.

**References:**

- [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) : convert the 2D array to 1D array.
- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) : filter only on `"Mueller, Klaus"`.
- [Array.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length): get the length of the filtered data
  which is the desired result.
- [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes): check if `Mueller, Klaus` is included in the text.

### Bonus info

Just for your information, my solution can be rewritten in one line of code if that's important to you:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat().filter(r=>r.includes("Mueller, Klaus")).length);
```

Comment: Sry, both ways do not work for me as they still alert "0"

Comment: @GeorgSchöppen post a screenshot of your sheet. Because I can't reproduce your issue. And actually post the full code you are using. You might have variables / code that interfere with my code.

Comment: @GeorgSchöppen also make sure your don't have extra spaces or capital letters. The searching keyword has to be exactly like that `Mueller, Klaus`. No extra spaces, no different uppercase or lowercase letters. Exactly like that.

Comment: Spreadsheetapp: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/beocv64jigtb0cf/testChatSpreadsheet.png?dl=0

Code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4ylqysb0n0aah2/testChatSpreadsheetCode.png?dl=0

Comment: @GeorgSchöppen this is not `Mueller, Klaus` but `Test Test ... Mueller, Klaus Test ..` Add this extra and very relevant information to your question. Try again my updated answer (the optimized code).

Comment: For real the rows are filled by chat requests and I want to write a tool to count the answers of customers to get statistics for example. Imagine many people sending requests and I want to get the amount of Klaus Mueller's requests